# How can I delete my wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

So I didn't have enough space on my current HDD for my wallet, the "install" stopped about halfway through because of this
I decided to delete the files it had created but I can't find them. I've searched almost my entire computer, and even went trough my entire appdata and documents folders manually but can't find anything regarding my monero wallet.

Where are these files located and how can I remove them?

Comment: Which "install"? There should not be any install. From where did you get that program? The "official" site is https://getmonero.org

Answer (score 4):

Blockchain is usually located in `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero`.

Wallet will be located wherever you started the CLI, or wherever you saved it with the GUI, if you ever made a wallet.

The wallet program will be in the folder into which you unpacked the .zip. There's no installation, you just start it from there. The only folder automatically created will be the `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` one.

Comment: > Blockchain is usually located in C:\ProgramData\bitmonero. This was it Thank you so much

Comment: On Linux, you can find it under the `~/.bitmonero` folder.